# C# Word vsto Add in Get Text of visible screen only

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-addins, word-interop

I'm trying to obtain text and range from currently visible screen(Page) of active document MS word.

I have try bellow code which is working fine with new document.

```
    IntPtr h = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
    h = NativeMethodsActiveScreen.FindWindowExW(h, new IntPtr(0), "_WwF", "");
    h = NativeMethodsActiveScreen.FindWindowExW(h, new IntPtr(0), "_WwB", null);
    h = NativeMethodsActiveScreen.FindWindowExW(h, new IntPtr(0), "_WwG", null);
    NativeMethodsActiveScreen.tagRECT t = new NativeMethodsActiveScreen.tagRECT();
    NativeMethodsActiveScreen.GetWindowRect(h, out t);
    Range r1 = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(t.left, t.top);
    Range r2 = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(t.right, t.bottom);
    Range r = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Range(r1.Start, r2.Start);
   //here r1 and r2 return wrong value in open document case as describe bellow
```

Here is the native mwthod which i have used

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
     public struct tagRECT
     {
          public int left;
          public int top;
          public int right;
          public int bottom;
     }
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowExW")]
public static extern System.IntPtr
                        FindWindowExW([System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()]
                            System.IntPtr hWndParent, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()]
                            System.IntPtr hWndChildAfter, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()]
                            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
                            string lpszClass, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()]
                            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
                            string lpszWindow);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowRect")]
public static extern System.IntPtr GetWindowRect([System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()]
                            System.IntPtr hWndParent, out tagRECT lpRect);
```

A problem occurs when I open saved document and try to get visible area text. At that time  `ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(x,y)` returns for `r1`: `range 0,0)` and for `r2`: `range 1,1)` (as listed above) every time.

can any one help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced same issue previously. I suggest you to try below solution. I thought you were facing issue due to only single page document, might be that's why "r2.Start" will return 1.

```
Range r1 = (Range)RibbonHelper.SharedApplicationInstance.Application.ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint((int)t.left, (int)t.top);
                Range r2 = (Range)RibbonHelper.SharedApplicationInstance.Application.ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint((int)t.right, (int)t.bottom);
                Range r = RibbonHelper.SharedApplicationInstance.ActiveDocument.Range(r1.Start, r2.Start);

                Range FullDocRange = RibbonHelper.SharedApplicationInstance.ActiveDocument.Range();
                if (r2.Start <= 1)
                {
                    r = FullDocRange;
                }
                RibbonHelper.VisibleAreaRange = r;
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: yes this can resolve the current issue but is It proper solution?. because placing hard code condition for r2.start range might be wrong when the document is blank and user try to type some thing.